# Pseudo class is not working as expected.. after hovering button ...paragraph is not getting displayed

Tags: html, css

```css
button { width: 100px; height: 30px; background-color: grey; }

p {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

button:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button>
   Click Me!
</button>
<p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi sint obcaecati 
   eligendi eos officia ut itaque deserunt repellat deleniti similique quis
   pariatu doloremque rem beatae accusamus, commodi esse eaque magnam.
</p>
```

after hovering on button paragraph is not getting displayed

Comment: `button:hover p` would select a `p` element that is a _child_ of the hovered button. You want the adjacent sibling combinator, or the general sibling combinator - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators

Comment: @CBroe Technically any descendant `p`, not just a child `p`

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use `button:hover+p`

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
}

p {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

button:hover+p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button>
        Click Me!
    </button>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi sint obcaecati eligendi eos officia ut itaque deserunt repellat deleniti similique quis pariatu doloremque rem beatae accusamus, commodi esse eaque magnam.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```css
button:hover p {display: block;}
```

use

```css
button:hover + p {display: block;}
```

as p and button are sibling elements.